# Upload items from user computer to a server asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I don't really know how to explain what I want to do.

I will try to explain what I am doing. I built a website in ASP.NET 4 (WebForms) and I want that my brother will be able to click on a button, choose a file from his computer and it will be uploaded to my server.

I have no idea how to do it. It sounds very hard to do and I am really stuck with this for a few days now.

I don't care if it will be with JavaScript, HTML or C#, I just really need it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an ASP.NET control made just for that, [the `FileUpload` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx).  Here's a [handy example](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/controls/file-upload-control/).

Note that it's notoriously difficult to style if you want to apply CSS and make it elegant, but there are more advanced ways around that.  Also, this won't give your web application access to the client's local files or anything like that, it's just a standard file open dialog box for the user to select a file and upload it.

I also *highly* recommend doing a lot of input checking when accepting files.  File type, file size, etc. are all important.

Comment: @Alon M: The file upload mechanism in ASP.NET uses the HTTP protocol's standards for posting a file.  It will work like any other HTTP interaction.  Any client which can connect to the server (and has no other restrictions between it and the server which would prevent standard HTTP interaction) would be able to use this.  In the house, outside the house, sitting up on the roof, in the neighbor's house, etc.  If the client can use the website, then the client can use the website.

Comment: I guess that for that to be 100% safe i need to work with https, and it will work there to. am i right?

Comment: @Alon M: I'm not sure what you're getting at.  Encrypting the channel will add a layer of security, yes.  But no single turn-key mechanism will make you "100% safe" (which is a very relative term).  If you're asking whether the file upload will work over HTTPS then the answer is yes.  HTTP and HTTPS are functionally equivalent, the latter is just encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options really.. use a traditional fileupload control (from the toolbox) or use the Ajax AsyncFileupload control.
 either way it will allow your brother to upload a file from his computer to your server.